# Не получается подключить библиотеку CANbus в QtCreator в RPi 3

Tags: qt, qtcreator, raspberry-pi

Задумка такова, используя библиотеку для работы с CAN на RPi (https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/can-bus-module-shield-tutorial-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/) и графический интерфейс написанный на Qt в Qt Creator, сделать приёмное устройство CAN с графическим интерфейсом. Но столкнулся с следующей проблемой: библиотека CAN никак не хочет подключаться, хотя пути до файлов .cpp  и .h указаны верно. Пока что суть программы заключается в инициализации CAN по нажатию на кнопку. Стоит также упомянуть, что анализатор в Qt creator не подчеркивает в include волнистой линией, а значит он нашел нужные файлы в указанных директориях. Заранее премного благодарен!
Ошибки:

```
in function 'MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()':
undefined reference to 'CAN::CAN()'
undefined reference to 'CAN::ON()'
undefined reference to 'CAN::begin(unsigned short)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Untitled.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH +=/home/pi/cooking/arduPi
INCLUDEPATH +=/home/pi/cooking/arduPi-api
INCLUDEPATH +=/home/pi/cooking/libraries/arduPiCANBUS
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "arduPiCAN.h"
#include "arduPi.h"
#include "arduPiUtils.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    CAN myCAN = CAN();
    myCAN.ON();
    myCAN.begin(500);
    /*Мой замечательный код, который появится после решения данной проблемы*/
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Нужно библиотеку откомпилировать,а потом готовый файл .a включить директивой `LIBS+=` в файле проекта.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, через пару часов смогу его опробовать. Но у меня есть вопрос. В папке данной библиотеки есть папка "bcm2835-1.46", как я понимаю, там содержатся файлы, необходимые для работы с данным CAN-адаптером. Так вот, там этих файлов пару десятков с различными расширениями, либо вовсе без них, нужно ли их как-то компилировать в библиотеку, если да, то как, если нет, то что с ними вообще делать?

Comment: Дайте хоть список файлов

Comment: В папке библиотеки "cooking" для работы с CAN есть следующие папки: "examples" - тут примеры, понятно; "libraries" - здесь находятся "arduPiCAN.h" и "arduPiCAN.cpp"; "arduPi-api" - здесь тоже находятся несколько .h и .cpp; "arduPi"  - здесь, помимо "arduPi.h" и "arduPi.cpp", находится папка "bcm2835-1.46". Сдержимое этой папки следующее: aclocal.m4, AUTHORS, ChangeLog, config.guess, config.h, config.h.in, config.log, config.status, config.sub, configure, configure.ac, COPYING, depcomp,  INSTALL, install-sh, ltmain.sh, Makefile, Makefile.am, Makefile.in, missing, NEWS, README,stamp-h1[см.далее]

Comment: test-driver. Также есть ещё папка "src". И содержание следующее: bcm2835.с, bcm2835.h, bcm2835.o, libbcm2835.a, test, Makefile, Makefile.am, Makefile.in. И внутри уже этой папки (благодарю за терпение) есть ещё папка ".deps". Cодержимое: test.Po, bcm2835.Po. Понимаю, что, возможно, перечислять просто списком файлы не очень удобно для вопсриятия, но что-то я не нашёл тут как добавлять принтскрины.

Comment: Так у вас библиотека вместе с системой сборки. Вы на windows развлекаетесь?

Comment: RPi 3. Сейчас пытался на Ubuntu скомпилировать, но он нес смог. Не смог определить устройство: "Unable to determine board revision from /proc/cpuinfo". Так что давайте отталкиваться от того, что я пытаюсь писать сразу на RPi.